# Issue in referencing Dll file

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

In My Wp7 project,It was referring to some Dll ,So i removed Dll files in debug and release folder of the project,I got the reference issue with toolkit and other Dll(Not sure).After referring the toolkit and i am stuck with the issue of

> the type or namespace name 'ChildWindow' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows.Controls' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

So i added the reference file ,and now i am getting the new error of

> 'GestureEventArgs' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs' and 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureEventArgs'

I am stuck with this reference issue,Have anyone faced this similar sort of issue.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that there are two namespaces (System.Windows.Input and Microsoft.Phone.Controls) that both have the GestureEventArgs class. Referencing two DLL's with the same named class is fine. The issue is that most likely you have `using System.Windows.Input` and `using Microsoft.Phone.Controls` at the top of your code file. This allows you to refer to GestureEventArgs without typing out the full name space (such as System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs) - however since you have two classes with the same name, you should refer to them by their fully qualified name.

So instead of:

```
    private void Test_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Try (if the System.Windows.Input GestureEventArgs is the class you want):

```
    private void Test_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Hi,I tried as suggested,pblm now i am facing is when i launch the simulator with particular project,i am getting MissingMethodException

Comment: Can you paste the xaml/c# you are using, so we can take a look at it?